# Backbone AJAX+CORS or JSONP requests appending originating URL

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I have been trying to make this work on and off for days now, and I believe I have finally exhausted Google.

My issue is making backbone respect the base URL.  I have tried everything from $.ajaxPrefilter to overriding sync in each model, but regardless of the method, when I set options.url to

dev.api.blah.com/route

I end up with a request to

originating-domain.com/dev.api.blah.com/route.

How do I kill the originating domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the protocol.

```
 url: 'http://dev.api.blah.com/route';
```

Comment: Yep, that was a face palm answer.  CORS worked out of the box as soon as I hit the right uri.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @David FYI you don't need to specify the protocol, the double slashes are what's important. `//dev.api.blah.com/route` will also work and will use the protocol that the originating page uses.